# How can I use stream.publish with @ tags using the Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a page, and I want to make a little competition. I'm using a static [FBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#FBML) tab and after users clicks on some choices they have to publish some text on their walls in order to enter the competition.

Everything is working great, but now I have a problem. I want to know how exactly to publish that text on their walls. I tried to search for something in FBML, [FBJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Iframes) or [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) that can send me the user ID to my server via Ajax and I can store that in my database, but for privacy purposes that is forbidden in pages.

Now I'm trying to tag my page's name (@mypagename) in `stream.publish` so users' posts will appear on my wall so I can track them and choose a winner from them, but I couldn't also do the tag thing.

How do I fix the `@tag` thing?

My publish code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attachment;//some data here
    Facebook.streamPublish('message here', attachment);
</script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use the [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) helper method:

```
function feed_via_ui() {
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
        message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!',
        to:'12334556' //UID
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
          alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
          alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    }
    );
}
```